# Subtract two rows of same table and sum the difference

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
OrNo    CurrentDate         PreviousDate        Finished    Amount
G988    02.05.2013 14:00:47 NULL                False       1560
G988    02.05.2013 21:30:00 02.05.2013 14:00:47 False       3170
G988    03.05.2013 06:00:00 02.05.2013 21:30:00 False       5095
G988    03.05.2013 07:46:24 03.05.2013 06:00:00 True        5254
```

Table Name: oldDate

I have this data, and I have to calculate the total amount on a single day but I need to also subtract the previous day's amount, so that only the amount which was produced today (current date) is calculated.

Current Date is the real date on which the order is processed and previous date is the last day's date on which this order was processed. Point me out if m not clear in explanation of the data, I tried ..

```
if t2.CurrentDate = t1.PreviousDate and datepart(t2.CurrentDate)= datepart(t1.CurrentDate) 

then
     if t1.CurrentDate>t2.CurrentDate

        then  @amount = t1.Amount

     else @amount = t2.Amount
```

I'm bad at dealing with joins .. :( so I have problems with this logic, I tried some other code from other examples but was not successful, any ideas will be really appreciated..

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I am using SQL Server database..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [FAQ] soon.  You've managed to tell us that you have a table, but you've not told us what its name is.  This is a surprisingly common error in SQL questions.  Please always provide a table name; it improves the consistency of the answers.  (It can be a made up name if the actual name in your database is too inscrutable, but tables have names.)

Comment: I'm sorry and thank you, I created this table to simplify the main table which has lots of this type of orders (OrNo), it has the name tabletting, as this data belongs to the medical tablets, it tells how much amount of tablets were produced on a single day. And i gave this table 'oldDate' name.

Comment: Hey @JonathanLeffler I'm stuck in similar problem, I want to subtract the sum of amount for a particular month which has status pending from the sum of amount for the same month which has paid status.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you could get a table with columns:

- OrNo
- CurrDate
- PrevDate
- CurrAmount
- PrevAmount

Then solving your problem would be trivial.  Given the `AnonymousTable`, this query generates the data:

```
SELECT a.OrNo,
       a.CurrentDate AS CurrDate, a.PreviousDate AS PrevDate,
       a.Amount AS CurrAmount,    b.Amount AS PrevAmount
  FROM AnonymousTable AS a
  JOIN AnonymousTable AS b
    ON a.OrNo = b.OrNo AND a.PrevDate = b.CurrDate
UNION
SELECT a.OrNo,
       a.CurrentDate AS CurrDate, a.PreviousDate AS PrevDate,
       a.Amount AS CurrAmount,    0 AS PrevAmount
  FROM AnonymousTable AS a
 WHERE a.PreviousDate IS NULL
```

So, presumably, you could write:

```
SELECT OrNo, CurrDate, CurrAmount - PrevAmount AS NewAmount
  FROM (SELECT a.OrNo,
               a.CurrentDate AS CurrDate, a.PreviousDate AS PrevDate,
               a.Amount AS CurrAmount,    b.Amount AS PrevAmount
          FROM AnonymousTable AS a
          JOIN AnonymousTable AS b
            ON a.OrNo = b.OrNo AND a.PrevDate = b.CurrDate
        UNION
        SELECT a.OrNo,
               a.CurrentDate AS CurrDate, a.PreviousDate AS PrevDate,
               a.Amount AS CurrAmount,    0 AS PrevAmount
          FROM AnonymousTable AS a
         WHERE a.PreviousDate IS NULL
       )
```

Equally clearly, if you put your mind to it, you can simplify things by writing:

```
SELECT a.OrNo,
       a.CurrentDate AS CurrDate, a.PreviousDate AS PrevDate,
       a.Amount - b.Amount AS NewAmount
  FROM AnonymousTable AS a
  JOIN AnonymousTable AS b
    ON a.OrNo = b.OrNo AND a.PrevDate = b.CurrDate
UNION
SELECT a.OrNo,
       a.CurrentDate AS CurrDate, a.PreviousDate AS PrevDate,
       a.Amount AS NewAmount
  FROM AnonymousTable AS a
 WHERE a.PreviousDate IS NULL
```

The key techniques here are the UNION query and the self-join.  Your data has consistent 'threading' of the dates and times, so the comparison between the current date and previous date columns is trivial.

Comment: Thanks once again, it is very helpful.