# Mysql - Find increased value over a week

Tags: mysql

Score Table

---

user_idx (int)

date (datetime)

score (int)

---

I need to find out how much total score has increased over a week from today's date. I know that I need two of the same user tables grouped by user_idx that one contains total scores from the past to today and the other contains total scores from the past to a date of a week ago.

After that, by substracting one from the other will give me the answer...  but I'm struggling to write effective sql query that does it.

I've tried

```
SELECT BLAH BLAH 
FROM (SELECT user_idx, COUNT(*) as last_week_study_amount 
      FROM user_table 
      WHERE date <= date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 1 WEEK) 
      GROUP BY user_idx) 
AS a WHERE .....
```

Could you help me :( ?

Comment: but realized that it's not a way to do it. So, I'm currently googling if it's possible to use JOIN syntax with SELECT.. FROM.. WHERE.. format to create another same table of it.

Comment: if that's still not an appropriate solution, I will start checking out UNION

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17215615/subtract-two-rows-of-same-table-and-sum-the-difference    I think this post is giving me some hints!

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT (SUM(score) - last_week_score) AS increased_score, 
FROM user a
JOIN (SELECT b.user_idx, COUNT(*) as last_week_score
  FROM userb
  WHERE date<= date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
  GROUP BY b.user_idx) As c ON a.user_idx = c.user_idx
WHERE DATE(date) <= DATE(NOW())
GROUP BY a.user_idx
```

I ended up writing this code and I think this one is working okay... not sure if it's the best or has a critical error. I will update it if it turns out to be a bad one...

Answer (score 0):

Let me clear you want to get total count in last week.

Try below query

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT user_idx, COUNT(*) as last_week_study_amount 
      FROM user_table 
      WHERE date <= date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 1 WEEK) 
      GROUP BY user_idx) 
AS a WHERE .....
```

Comment: Mmm... not quite. I want to find increased score over a week. In other words, Total Score - Total Score until the last week.

Comment: okk then i think there is no any problem in sql you provide.please run only subquery and check you got result or not?

Comment: Doesn't Inner Select gives already-grouped-table that cannot be reused for outer WHERE?

Comment: will you provide full query?